# Taking substring from string between " sign // C++ Builder

Tags: c++, string, load, substring, c++builder

I've got problem with following task. I need to load output txt data from other program to my one and search it for following string:

"zhi": 97.92716217041016,

and especially numerical value (97.92...). The "," sign is separator between other exported values.

I was trying to deal with that in c++ builder following way:
1. read file
2. load lines as strings
3. find position of zhi
4. add 6 to position - this will point on numbers
5. delete everything before new pointer
6. delete everything after 15 char

I know there have to be some easier way but I'm beginner with c++.

Can someone guide me what function I can use to find numbers between "zhi": and , ?

Comment: Is this JSON?  If so, use a JSON parser.

Comment: Is the problem with positioning the file or with parsing the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::getline` to read file as `std::string` types.
Use `string::find` to get the position of the text after `"zhi":`.
Use `string::find` to get the position of the ','.
Use `string::substr` to get a copy of the string between the two positions.

Remember, modifying files in the middle is difficult, especially if you have to delete or insert more characters.

The traditional method of modifying files is:
1. Copy all unchanged content from original file to new file.
2. Write changed text to new file.
3. Write remaining unchanged text to new file.
4. Close all files.